# Android Icon is pixelated/ blurry

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I loaded an icon with the Android Asset Studio.
It created me mdpi, hdpix hdpi, xxhdpi and a xxxhdpi icon
but the icons are pixelated and blurry :( 
Here the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Android Studio's Image Asset wizard is not designed to create images that are 144dp on a side. That wizard is more for action bar icons, notification icons, and the like, all of which are much smaller.

Comment: but it created one icon with the site of 144x144. How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try a vector graphic.

This will scale to any size you want without being blurry. Save the graphic as a .SVG and then you can convert it to an Android Vector Drawable .XML file (Google "SVG to Vector Convertor" for a convertor).

Put the resulting .XML Android Vector Drawable in the `res\drawable` folder.

Comment: the tool does not work with a vector file which has a gradient. Do you know a alternative way?

Comment: Vector Drawable doesn't support gradients so it's not the right solution for you.